# Python - locals() and closure

Tags: python, closures, locals

I can not find an adequate explanation for this behavior.

```py
>>> def a():
...     foo = 0
...     print locals()
...     def b():
...         print locals()
...     b()

>>> a()
{'foo': 0}
{}
```

But:

```py
>>> def a():
...     foo = 0
...     print locals()
...     def b():
            foo
...         print locals()
...     b()

>>> a()
{'foo': 0}
{'foo': 0}
```

I understand that in the second case there is a closure, but I can not find a detailed description of what actually is and under what conditions should return the function `locals()`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd accept Michael Shuller's answer (the check mark under the upvote/downvote on his comment). Share the love and show appreciation for his efforts!

Comment: @rsegal The answer of Rostyslav Dzinko is depeer.

Comment: True! I should have phrased it better: I was trying to say more that you should shower your favor on _an_ answer, rather than necessarily my favorite.

But I did, and do still, feel that Michael's answer more directly addressed your question, pointing out that Python searches up-scope for ambiguous values, which was the behavior you demonstrated!

Comment: @rsegal I was interested in the internals. To be honest, I also have not fully satisfied with the answer by Rostyslav Dzinko. I need more details!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

locals() built-in function prints local symbol table which is bound to a **code object**, and filled up when interpreter receives a name in a source code.

Second example, when disassembled, will contain **LOAD_GLOBAL foo** bytecode instruction in **b** function code. This LOAD_GLOBAL instruction will move up the scope, find outer foo name and bind it to the code object by adding name offset into **co_names** attribute of the closure's (function b) code object.

locals() function prints local symbol table (as was said before, co_names attribute of function's code object).

Read more about code objects [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-880).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't assign to `foo` within the closure, Python resolves it to the `foo` of the scope one level up (and on up until it finds a `foo` somewhere or throws an exception).

By mentioning `foo` within `b()` in the second example, you put `foo` into the locals within `b()`, but it resolves to the `foo` within the body of `a()`. If you assign, say, `foo = 1` in `b()`, you would see

```
 {'foo': 0}
 {'foo': 1}
```

as the output.

Comment: Thanks, but i need more internal details :(